# Rate Limits using Python/Pandas to download a large CSV from remote server

Tags: pandas

I'm using Pandas 1.5.1 to download a large file (~3GB) from an API. This API has rules about multiple requests, so I need to be careful about making too many requests.

I have used the "chunk" feature in Pandas before, but it's unclear whether this is making several requests to the server or if it's making one request. The [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking) is unclear on this detail. It mentions returning a TextFileReader object, but I haven't been able to find out what that would mean for the server side of things.

**Does anyone understand if the following code makes a single request or multiple requests to the server?**

```
i = 0
for chunk in pd.read_csv("https://website.com/data/v6/file.csv", chunksize=10000):
    i += 1
    chunk.to_csv(f"data{i}.csv")
```

Comment: my understanding is that this would make many requests. can you just download the file once and then open it using the chunked reader?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. It seemed "expensive" to download and then chunk read from the local file, but you're right that would definitely work!

Comment: Oh yeah - depends on what you’re optimizing for. The api response and transit time will probably be your biggest bottlenecks. Streaming is faster than caching on disk but if the file is too big to load in one go then minimizing api calls by writing to disk and then reading in by chunks is probably a good bet.